# Bootstrap JavaScript FallBack

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrapping

I am currently developing a web application with bootstrap as my UI framework with JSP/Servlet technology on the back end.

I would like to know how to make a safe and clean fallback in case JS is not enabled on the client's browser.

I have a link that opens a modal and I want to know if I could make the link go to another page instead of opening the modal in case JS is not enabled.

Thank you

Comment: how about setting the href attribute for the link and removing it from javascript?

Comment: If i set the href attribute for the link, the modal opens the content of the link itself not the custom content for the modal that I designed

Comment: That's why you should delete it when the page loads.

Comment: Oh, i get it. Thanks.

Comment: Still, unless you have to support some old corporate environments where js is disabled for security reasons. I advise against doing this. It's much better to use the noscript element to show a message to the user when they have js disabled. The number of people that have js disabled is very low, and it costs too much  to make a website work without it to be worth it.